# flutter google drive upload

Tags: flutter, google-drive-api

We know that everyone can upload content to a specific google drive with drive upload forms even without signing in to the google account. So is there any way to integrate this feature with flutter (ex: with  APIs)?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

To [upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) files to Google Drive without the need for the user to log in with their account there are three possibilities:

1. Using your account and generating a token that is [refreshed](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#5.-refresh-the-access-token,-if-necessary.) as needed.
2. Using a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts), this can upload the files to a folder shared with your account. The holder can either use this account or your account.
3. Using a service account with [Domain-Wide Delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation). Users can upload files directly to your account as if they were using it.

### Reference

- [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)
- [Refresh token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#5.-refresh-the-access-token,-if-necessary.)
- [Service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts)
- [Domain-Wide Delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation)